# Multiple user-account creation

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-management

I'm running a workshop and I have a Windows 2008 server, I want to allow my students (nearly 90) to upload some of their work to the server via ftp. They are not part of any Active Directoy, so which is the best way to create their accounts and let them upload their files? I saw once that Moodle lets you upload a Excel file with multiple user information and create their accounts easily, is there something like this for windows accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to create accounts for them within the Active Directory. You can do this with [CSVDE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787549(WS.10).aspx). Essentially you create a file in Excel, then save it as a CSV. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/Logon_CSVDE_Bulk.htm).

Comment: +1 - That's a fairly reasonable tutorial, and overall imports w/ CSVDE is a sound strategy.